# React Native: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-security

I came accross a bug while trying to create a new group for my app using React Native and Firebase. I wanted to add the user id for the one creating the group but i tried different methods and kept getting errors, as well as this error(FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions) even though i dont have the user id.

here's my code:

```
import { View, Text, Switch, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn'
import { ChatBubbleLeftRightIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/outline'
import { authentication, db } from '../firebase-config'
import{
    collection,
    addDoc,
    add
} from '@firebase/firestore'


const AddGroup = ({navigation}) => {
    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
    const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState('');
    const [numParticipants, setnumParticipants] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const toggleSwitch = () => {
        setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState)
    };

    const tailwind = useTailwind();




    const newGroup = async () => {
        await db
        addDoc(collection(db, 'Groups'), {
            
            gorupTitle: groupName,
            groupNum: numParticipants,
            groupDes: description,
            groupPriv: isEnabled,
            
        })
        .then(() => {
            navigation.goBack()
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
        return () =>unsubscribe();
    }


    const onRegionChange = (region) => {
        console.log(region)
    }

    const onChanged = (text) => {
        let newText = '';
        let numbers = '0123456789';
    
        for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if(numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1 ) {
                newText = newText + text[i];
            }
            else {
                alert("please enter numbers only");
            }
        }
        setnumParticipants(newText);
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder='Name' value={groupName} onChangeText={text => setGroupName(text)} style={tailwind('')}/>
                <ChatBubbleLeftRightIcon />
            </View>
            <TextInput placeholder='Description' value={description} onChangeText={text => setDescription(text)} style={tailwind('')}/>
            <View>
                <Text>Public</Text>
                <Switch
                    trackColor={{false: '#767577', true: '#1e40af'}}
                    thumbColor={isEnabled ? 'white' : 'white'}
                    onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                    value={isEnabled} />
            </View>
            <TextInput
                keyboardType='numeric'
                onChangeText={text => onChanged(text)}
                value={numParticipants}
                placeholder='Maximum Number of participants'
                style={tailwind('')}
                maxLength={10}
                onSubmitEditing={newGroup}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={newGroup}>
                <Text>Create</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
  
export default AddGroup;
```

I was hoping for the app the functionality create a new group with the id of the creator as well as the date and time of creating